# Python - 'in' keyword and if-statements not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have looked for an answer to my question, but it seems there are none for my problem specifically. Which has lead me to believe this is a simple error............

```
def intest():

  choice = raw_input("> ")

  if "hello" or "world" in choice:
    print "There is hello or world in 'choice'"
  elif "bye" or "cya" in choice:
    print "There is bye or cya in 'choice'"
  else:
    print "Go again"
    return intest()

intest()
```

When run, no matter what is typed in the `raw_input`, the first `if-statement` is the one that executes. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statements like,

```
if "hello" in choice or "world" in choice:
```